# Scroll to item in overflow:auto div

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have an overflow:auto div with specific max-height. That div contains many items as a list. I try to make a scroll script but seem it missing something.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/UX5cd/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try resetting the div's scrollTop to zero before you read the chosen item's offset

Answer (score 1):

try adding this:

body {  margin: 0; padding: 0;  }

to your stylesheet;

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

[code]
`$(".orderedList").scrollToElement($(".orderedList .selected"));`
[/code]

KR